# Graphics library - React Native

Tags: graphics, react-native

I am creating an app using React Native. I want to render some cool graphics (eg. A screen displaying a man running etc.) in my app screens. What shall I learn to be able to do so?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this might be what you're looking for 
[React-Canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-canvas)

The library lets user draw things in canvas as well as image transition with multi layer and more by using components.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [Expo's GLView](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/gl-view/). It provides you an OpenGL ES render target.

Answer (score -1):

You could look at awesome-react on github. there is packages listed where you can just exporte things created using adobe after effects